# Matplotlib/Pandas: How to plot multiple scatterplots within different locations in the same plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I often have two pandas dataframes, which I would like to plot within the same plot. Normally these are two samples, and I would like to contrast their properties, as an example:

[image]

The x axis simply has two locations, the left for the first dataset, and the right for the second dataset.

In matplotlib, one can plot multiple datasets within the same plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(100)
y = range(100,200)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter(x[:4], y[:4], s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='first')
ax1.scatter(x[40:],y[40:], s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='second')
plt.show()
```

[image]

However,

(1) How do you separate your datasets into two compartmentalized locations like the first example?

(2) How do you accomplish this with two pandas dataframes? Do you merge them and then specify two locations for plotting?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a seaborn stripplot? https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html#seaborn.stripplot

Comment: @tom Yes! This works perfectly. I think I do have to merge dataframes into one in order to use this though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `return_type='axes'` to get `data1.boxplot` to return a matplotlib Axes object. Then pass that axes to the second call to boxplot using `ax=ax`. This will cause both boxplots to be drawn on the same axes.

```
ax = df1.plot()
df2.plot(ax=ax) 


a1=a[['a','time']]
ax = a1.boxplot(by='time', meanline=True, showmeans=True, showcaps=True, 
            showbox=True, showfliers=False, return_type='axes')
a2 = a[['c','time']]
a2.boxplot(by='time', meanline=True, showmeans=True, showcaps=True, 
       showbox=True, showfliers=False, ax=ax)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely follow without more code. `df1` is the first dataframe to be plotted, `df2' is the second. Your code above places both dataframe scatterplots in the same frame?

Comment: Yes that would place both scatterplots in the same frame, can you specify what issues you're having

Comment: The full code is easier to follow. How does one use `return_type='axes'`?